# Python: Waiting for all threads to be at a specific point in code to continue

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await

I want to run a process on multiple threads, but after each iteration the processes should wait for a global process to finish. More specifically:

I have a list of "ants", which all construct a tour on a graph (this I want to do concurrently). This happens many times over many iterations. After each ant completed their iteration, I want to update the graph. How can I best do this? some code I have:

```py
ants = [Ant() for _ in range(50)] # 50 ants in a list

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as ex:
    # start threads on slices of ants
    f1 = ex.submit(solve_aco, ants[:n_ants//4], epochs)
    f2 = ex.submit(solve_aco, ants[n_ants//4:n_ants // 2], epochs)
    f3 = ex.submit(solve_aco, ants[n_ants // 2:n_ants // 2 + n_ants // 4], epochs)
    f4 = ex.submit(solve_aco, ants[n_ants // 2 + n_ants // 4:], epochs)

    # while not finished: if all ants are waiting, update graph

def solve_aco(ants, epochs):
    for _ in range(epochs):
        # Construct route through graph
        # Wait until graph update, then continue next epoch
```

I have tried some things with threading.Condition() but I can't seem to figure out where and how to wait / notify threads properly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `concurrent.futures.wait()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-functions) you can wait for the work in your worker threads to complete before continuing.

BTW: Due to the global interpreter lock, if the work you're doing in solve_aco all happens in pure Python code, multithreading will not give you a performance boost. You can use the `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead, though it comes with more overhead. Basically, if executing `solve_aco()` takes a long time (many milliseconds), use a ProcessPoolExecutor. If not, you're probably better off just working in a single thread.